# how to create regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

Regular expression for removing all lines between `#if X` and `#endif //#if X` 
Note the C style comment is important and needs to be taken into account

```
#if X
....
.....
#endif //#if X
```

The following is not giving desired o/p: So is the re right ?

```
re.compile("#if.*?#endif //#if X", re.MULTILINE + re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: What is the problem ("not the desired o/p" is rather vague)?

Answer (score 2):

So far, you have just compiled your regex, you haven't done anything with it yet.

You need to do this:

```
myregex = re.compile(r"#if.*?#endif //#if X", re.DOTALL)
result = myregex.sub("", subject)
```

where `subject` is the string you want to work on (and `""` is the replacement string).

You don't need the `re.MULTILINE` parameter since you're not using the start-/end-of-line anchors at all.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 're.MULTILINE + re.DOTALL' try 're.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL' , it's a bit field

Comment: Although that shouldn't matter here because all the flags are powers of 2, so adding and "oring" them will yield the same result. You're still right, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.compile(r'#if\s+([A-Z]+)$.+?#endif\s+//\s*#if\s+\1', re.M | re.S)
```